# Can I use an embedded lambda with the Contains method?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, contains

I want to filter a list with `FindAll`

If I write:

```
.FindAll(
    p => p.Field == Value && 
    p.otherObjList.Contains(otherObj));
```

it's ok, but if I write

```
.FindAll(
    p => p.Field == Value && 
    p.otherObjList.Contains(
        q => q.Field1 == Value1 && 
        q.Field2 == Value2));
```

I get C# syntax error message: **Unknown Method FindAll(?) of .. the otherObjList**

I cannot define the otherObj exactly, because I know only the values of two fields, Field1 and Field2.

What have I done wrong? What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Contains()` method for both most collection types as well as the LINQ version expects an argument of the same type as the collection, not a lambda.

It appears you are just trying to check if any item matches some condition.  You should use the [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) method.

```
.FindAll(p => p.Field == Value
           && p.otherObjList.Any(q => q.Field1 == Value1 && q.Field2 == Value2))
```

Comment: @refactor: he probably will forget.

Comment: Sorry, I've asked the question, but I wasn't registered, and I couldn't accept the answer without registering. But I've compensated it.